# Exclude nested entity data and only care about Id with update in EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I create a new `WorkoutProgram` object, add new `ExerciseInWorkoutProgram` and add an existing `Exercise` and want to save it to my database.

**Update** with some usage-code, yes very simple, no DTOs:

Creating the 'WorkoutProgram' on client

```
var exercise= await HttpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<Exercise>("Exercice/1");
var workoutProgram = new WorkoutProgram();
workoutProgam.Exercices = new List();
workoutProgam.Exercices = new ExerciseInWorkoutProgram() {Exercice = exercise};
_httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync<WorkoutProgram>($"WorkoutProgram", workoutProgram);
```

On server

```
var operation = await _dbContext.WorkoutPrograms.AddAsync(workoutProgram);
await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

I get

> SqlException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Exercises' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

which I understand, as EF Core tries to insert the `Exercises` I already have in the database.

How can I tell EF Core, do not try to update `Exercise` entries, just use the Id to create the relationship?

WorkoutProgram

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public List<ExerciseInWorkoutProgram> Exercices { get; set; }
```

ExerciseInWorkoutProgram

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public int Sets { get; set; }
public int Reps { get; set; }
public Exercice Exercice { get; set; }
```

Exercise

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Content { get; set; }
```

I can change the `ExerciseInWorkoutProgram` class

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public int Sets { get; set; }
public int Reps { get; set; }
public ExerciseId { get; set; }
[NotMapped]
public Exercise Exercise { get; set; }
```

Then update works but I when query the database I need to get the `Exercise` manually

Using a stub, as described by Steve Py works perfectly.

Comment: You need to **show us the code** that creates those new objects, and assigns the existing one, and then saves to the database, using EF Core! We can't see and read your screen, nor can we read your mind - you need to **SHOW US!**

Comment: There are many ways to do what you want, but none of them includes `[NotMapped]` attribute. This attribute does not solve anything, just forget about its existence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally when creating a new ExerciseWorkoutProgram provided just an Exercise ID, you should consider fetching the Exercise and associating it. While this may seem like an unnecessary round trip to the database, it does serve to validate that the Exercise ID you received actually does refer to an existing record:

```
var exercise = _context.Exercises.Single(x => x.Id == exerciseId);
var exerciseWorkoutProgram = new ExerciseWorkoutProgram
{
     // details...
     Exercise = exercise
}
_context.ExerciseWorkoutPrograms.Add(exerciseWorkoutProgram);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

If the Exercise ID isn't valid you get an exception.

Alternatively, if you trust that the Exercise ID cannot be tampered with and will point to a valid row in all cases, or are content to address FK violations at Save, then you can use a stub if necessary:

```
bool usedStub = false;
var exercise = _context.Exercises.Local.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == exerciseId);
if (exercise == null)
{
    exercise = new Exercise { Id = exerciseId };
    _context.Attach(exercise);
    usedStub = true;
}

var exerciseWorkoutProgram = new ExerciseWorkoutProgram
{
     // details...
     Exercise = exercise
}
_context.ExerciseWorkoutPrograms.Add(exerciseWorkoutProgram);
_context.SaveChanges();

if (usedStub)
    Context.Entry(exercise).State = EntityState.Detached;
```

What this code does is check the local tracking cache for the given exercise via the `.Local`. This doesn't result in a trip to the DB, but will report back whether the DbContext happens to be tracking the desired entity already and returns it if so. If it isn't tracking one, then we will create and attach a stub entity to associate. Attaching the entity with the ID tells EF "this is an existing row", however we do need to check the cache first because attaching an entity while one is already tracked will result in an error. Since it isn't a complete exercise, after associating and saving our exercise workout program, we should detach it so that EF doesn't return this incomplete stub of an entity in future queries where we might want to get data from the Exercise.

Answer (score 0):

When you attach an entity to the context as "added", all untracked entities in its object graph will also be attached as "added" and EF will try to insert new records for them.  What you need to do is attach the existing entity as "unchanged" before it's used or update its state to such after it's been attached via the ancestor object's object graph.

Alternatively, expose the FK values as properties as set them instead of a navigation property.